# PHP: Declare interface incompatibility

Tags: php, interface

Is there any way in PHP to declare that two interfaces are incompatible?
That is, to prevent a class from implementing both of them at once?

Ideally without creating meaningless dummy methods ..

Comment: How exactly are two interfaces incompatible?

Comment: As @Machavity says, interfaces are just contracts, so you cannot do it. You could try to achieve it with an [Abstract Class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) implementing a method that calls the "interfaced" (abstract) methods and throwing an exception if both interfaces exist.

Answer (score 2):

There's not any way to do this inside an interface because the interface doesn't actually implement, it only defines.

You can always have your implementation do that kind of test using [ReflectionClass::implementsInterface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.implementsinterface.php) or [class_implements](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php), but it sounds like people are writing new classes and that's the root problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to add a function with the same name to both, but as you said.. you prefer not to implement 'meaningless dummy methods'.

It sounds to me that there's probably a better way to solve your problem though ;)

Answer (score 1):

@Machavity and @Evert are right. Crutch:):

```
trait Compatibility{
private $incompatible_couples = array(
                         'Foo'=> array('A','C')
                       );

public function checkInterfaces($classname){
   $class_interfaces = class_implements($classname);
   // array(3) { ["A"]=> string(1) "A" ["B"]=> string(1) "B" ["C"]=> string(1) "C" }

   $couple = $this->incompatible_couples[$classname];
   if (count($couple)==count(array_intersect($class_interfaces,$couple))){
       die('Error: interfaces '.implode(' and ',$couple).' are incompatible');
   }
 }
}

interface A{
 //...
 }

interface B{
  //...
}

interface C{
  //...
}

class Foo implements A,B,C{
  use Compatibility; 

  function __construct(){
   self::checkInterfaces(__CLASS__); // checing interface compatibility
   //....
  }
}

var_dump(new Foo()); 
// Error: interfaces A AND C are incompatible.
```